# How to validate a textfield in pageablelistview in java wicket

Tags: java, wicket

i have added a pageable listview with two components,one is text field and other is a dropdown. Normal way of checking for validation is by adding a feedback panel.But when same method is used in grid its giving an error saying that feedback component with wicket:id="xy" has already been parsed.
is there any way to validate those components? 
[JAVA CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5e34.jpg)    [HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vca7H.jpg)

Comment: When you say "the same method" what method are you referring to? Additionally, could you provide a code snippet explaining your usage, i.e. how you instantiate your feedback panel(s) and your form components as well as any other relevant code for the relationship between them.

Comment: @WiseTree i have added my html and java codes in the description

Comment: Could you also provide the error that wicket produces?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the code (e.g. your overridden [`Form#onSubmit()`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Form.html#onSubmit()) or [`Form#onError()`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Form.html#onError()), one of your Ajax behaviors, etc.) you add the component with wicket ID "FeedbackSubQuestions_" again, even though this component has already been added before. Something like the following:

```
public class MyPage extends WebPage {

    public MyPage() {
        this.add(new FeedbackPanel("FeedbackSubQuestions_"));
        this.add(new Form<Void>("myForm"){
            @Override
            protected void onError() {
                // This call the produce the error as the feedback component is already in the component hierarchy
                MyPage.this.add(new FeedbackPanel("FeedbackSubQuestions_"));
            }
        });
        ...
        Adding all the form components with validation and their ajax behaviors
        ...        
    }
}
```

In wicket, once you construct the component hierarchy, subsequent interactions with the page do not need to reinitialise any of it anymore. That is, once you add the feedback panel in order for it to display your feedback you do not need to add this panel again. If there are errors to be displayed (e.g. a form validation fails, or [`Component#error(String)`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#error(java.io.Serializable)) is called manually) the feedback will pick those up automatically when the feedback panel is being rendered again (e.g. when you add it to your ajax response or the whole page is being re-rendered as part of the form submission process).

Comment: i am using a editable grid to display the textbox.so everytime i add a new row .that error pops up .i dont know if feed back panel is allowed in Grid.

Comment: If you are referring to `GridView` then yes it is.